# Which dependencies are needed for using the Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar, android-appcompat, androidx

I'm trying to create a Navigation Drawer. For that I need to use a toolbar.
I have the following dependencies:

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

And in my layout xml I have:

```
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/primaryColor"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

In my Java:

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class TestMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ToolBar toolBar;
```

And I get the following error when I try to build:

```
error: cannot find symbol
    private ToolBar toolBar;
            ^
  symbol:   class ToolBar
```

Also Android Studio says:

[image]

Which dependencies am I missing?

Comment: check `import packageName.R;` and `import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;` added or not. Then Clean-Rebuild.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it, I do import the `import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;`. I'll edit my question.

Comment: show `import ..R` section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class TestMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ToolBar toolBar;  // here
```

Replace "ToolBar" with "Toolbar"

Answer (score 1):

In your code there is a **typo**:
`ToolBar` instead of `Toolbar` in the line: `private ToolBar toolBar;`

About your question:

> Which dependencies are needed for using the Toolbar?

The class `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` is included in the

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.x'
```